# How to use recursion to calculate the max length of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion, maxlength

Here is the code that counts the maximum length in a nested list.

```
def max_length(obj):
    """
    Return the maximum length of obj or any of its sublists, if obj is a list.
    otherwise return 0.

    @param object|list obj: object to return length of
    @rtype: int

    >>> max_length(17)
    0
    >>> max_length([1, 2, 3, 17])
    4
    >>> max_length([[1, 2, 3, 3], 4, [4, 5]])
    4
    """
    if isinstance(obj,int):
        return 0
    else:
        return max([len(x) for x in obj])
```

The code is wrong as I don't know how to correctly combine `len()` function and recursion. What should I do?

Comment: You are not calling the method recursively for one ;) so there is no recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using recursion here at all. Recursion invovles calling a method inside the same method. One way of doing this can be  as follows. Note that there are three cases here,

1. When the `obj` is only an `int`eger, you need to return `0`
2. When the `obj` is a `list` with `int`egers you need to return the `len`gth  of the `list`
3. When the `obj` is a heterogeneous `list`, you need to *recurse*.

---

A code example can be

```
>>> def max_length(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj,int):
...         return 0
...     elif all(isinstance(i,int) for i in obj):
...             return len(obj)
...     else:
...         return max(max_length(i) for i in obj)
... 
>>> max_length(17)
0
>>> max_length([1, 2, 3, 17])
4
>>> max_length([[1, 2, 3, 3], 4, [4, 5]])
4
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
def nested_list(l):
    if type(l) is not list:
        return 0

    lens = [len(l)]

    for x in l:
        lens.append(nested_list(x))
    return max(lens)
```

... and if you want to be more Pythonic and duck-type it ...

```
def nested_list(l):
    try:
        lens = [len(l)]
    except TypeError:
        return 0

    for x in l:
        lens.append(nested_list(x))
    return max(lens)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to your code:

`def max_length(obj):
   if isinstance(obj,int):
       return 0
   else:
       return max(len(obj), max([max_length(i) for i in obj]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
if isinstance(obj, int):
    result.append(0)
else:
    for sublist in obj:
        result.append(max_length(sublist))
        result.append(len(obj))
return max(result)
```

This would work perfectly. Some of the code above isn't giving the right answer.